# Getting Datepicker to work in cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I'm trying to figure out why datepicker isn't working for me. This is in a cshtml view. I'm feeding the datepicker function the proper id but it is not working.

Page Source:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        <label for="EFFECTIVE_DATE1">EFFECTIVE_DATE1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="EFFECTIVE_DATE1" name="EFFECTIVE_DATE1" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EFFECTIVE_DATE1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

View code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head/>

 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
    </div>
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

**Update:** Here is the entire Page

```
@model BillingApp.Models.EFT_INFORMATION

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";
}
@section featured2 {
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>Combined App</title><meta name="description" content="website description">        <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/themes/style.css" title="style">
<div id="logo"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
<img src="@Url.Content("\\Content\\images\\logo.jpg")"/></a></div>
    <div class="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
    }
}
preload(
    "\\Content\\images\\logo.jpg"
)
//--><!]]>
</script>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logo_text">
      <h1><a href="index.html"><span class="logo_colour"></span></a></h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li> 
    </ul></div>
</div>
<div id="site_content">     
  <div id="content">

<style type="text/css">
p { display: inline }
p.msg {
    color: red;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
<h1>Welcome to the EFT Information Creation Page!</h1>
      <p>&#8202Please fill out the fields below to create a new entry and row of data.</p><br />    <br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true){
@*
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EEID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EEID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EEID)
    </div>*@

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
    </div>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
</div>
<script>
 $(function () {
     $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker();
 });
</script>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
    </div><br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value=" Create "/>   

    </p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "EFTInformation", "Billing")
</div>
}
<img class="logo" src="../../Content/images/logo.jpg">
<style type="text/css">
img.logo {
display: block;
margin-top: -24px;
margin-left: 351px;
margin-right: 351px;
height: 50px;
width: 135px;
}
</style>
      <style type="text/css">
#username {
    position: absolute;
    top:172px;
    left: calc(50% + 268px);
}
</style>
<div id="username"><p style="color: rgb(255,251,241);">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p></div>
</div></div>
<div id="content_footer"></div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body></html>
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Update:** Commented out most of the view except for the elements necessary for datepicker to work. It's still not working.

```
@model BillingApp.Models.EFT_INFORMATION

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";
}
@section featured2 {

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head><body>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TABLE_NUMBER1)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)
    </div>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1) 
</div>
<script>
 $(function () {
     $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-MM-dd' });
 });
</script>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TAX_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BANK_NAME)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPANY_NAME1)
    </div><br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value=" Create "/>   

    </p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "EFTInformation", "Billing")
</div>
}
}
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HEAD is misconfigured -

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head/>  <----- This line

 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
    </div>
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

That line should be `</head>`

### Working code for me

---

Index.cshtml

```
@model JqueryUIProject.Models.FakeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

FakeModel.cs

```
using System;

namespace JqueryUIProject.Models
{
    public class FakeModel
    {
        public DateTime EFFECTIVE_DATE1;
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JqueryUIProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BobFrancis I copied your code and pasted into a fresh new mvc project with nothing else in it. It works for me. Are you sure that there isn't some other code on the page that might be colliding with your datapicker?

Comment: @BobFrancis I added in the working code from my test project.

Comment: Not that I'm able to find. Does it make a difference that my model definition for EFFECTIVE_DATE1 is not of type DateTime?

Comment: @BobFrancis I don't think so, I just changed mine to a string and there was no problem loading the datepicker. Maybe I need you entire page code?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what's going on. Your jquery script declarations should be in your @scripts section. Do you have version control set up so that you can just strip things out and revert? I would just erase everything on this page except what you need to display your EFFECTIVE_DATE1 field and the function that adds the datepicker, and see if that runs on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Index.cshtml

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#DOB").click(function () {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                }).focus();
            });
        });
</script>
 <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => Model.First().DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-5">

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.First().DOB, new { @Value = Model.First().DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), @class = "form-control", required = "required" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.First().DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

*** you start jquery click  function***

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function() {

    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});

OR


 $("#EFFECTIVE_DATE1").click(function() {

    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```